# Serializing WebSocket objects in .Net Core

Tags: c#, websocket

Creating the server based on System.Net.WebSocket is easy enough, the client sockets connect and then I can keep them in a concurrent dictionary, something like ConcurrentDictionary<string,WebSocket>(), everything works.

But this is not good for the real application, where there would be several instances of the same WebSocket server running behind the same address, and the responses coming back should actually hit the specific WebSocket server, which beats the puporse of it and represents a single point of failure. So I need to keep the WebSocket objects in a database, or Azure storage table, or something like that, where all server instances can have access to the client sockets, so that they can use them to send messages back to the client.

I tried many things but could not find a way to serialize the WebSocket. JSON serialization does not work, and binary one neither since nothing is serializable in that abstract class, and besides the binary one is considered obsolete now and should not be used. So any ideas on how to go about this?

I do not want to use SignalR under any circumstances.

Thank you.

Comment: A WebSocket object is transient - attempting to save it between sessions does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Understood, but it actually does make sense. The connection gets established and is kept open, by sending the ping requests every 120 seconds or something. This is above the TCP stack, since the protocol changes when one uses the ws, and from there on it got nothing to do with TCP and http protocol. But if you have a backend then one cannot have just one single server that keeps all client sockets in process, so that it can push data from the server side. There has to be several servers, each in its own process, behind the load balancer, that can operator on the same pool of connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be misunderstanding how load balancing works with WebSockets. A WebSocket connection is very much like that of a regular 'socket' (hence the name, WebSocket).

A message sent through a WebSocket will only ever go to the server that the socket is connected to. A single WebSocket connection will only ever directly talk to one server.

Comment: Thank you, I guess no way to do this then.